# How can I get my Radeon graphics card to work after upgrading to 16.04?

Tags: drivers, graphics, kubuntu, radeon, amd-graphics

After upgrading Kubuntu from 15.04 (via 15.10) to 16.04, the Radeon driver is not loaded, even though my graphics card is in [the list of supported cards](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver).

If I boot from a 16.04 live USB stick then yes the graphics card is recognised and used properly, so it must be a software configuration issue with my current installation

Kernel 4.4.0-57-generic 64-bit

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM] Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM] Kernel modules: radeon
```

I do have this in my `xorg.log`:

```
[ 26.556] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section. [ 26.556] (II) UnloadModule: "radeon"
```

Anyone have any ideas, Thanks.

Comment: Reviewers: Although I hope the asker of this question expands their answer to give specific details about how they found and removed the `fglrx` packages that were preventing the system from working, this is still a problem that other users could face, clearly presented, with a known solution (and the solution has even been posted as an answer). Please do not close this as "Off Topic > a problem that can't be reproduced."

Answer (score 2):

Solved, there were still `fglrx` packages installed and I needed to remove them

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to solve this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)